# OpenCV 2.3 - undefined reference to cvCreateButton - Eclipse

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am trying to use the Qt new functions described here:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/qt_new_functions.html#cv-createbutton

And I also found this topic on SO:
[openCV 2.2 createButton LNK 2019 error in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458668/opencv-2-2-createbutton-lnk-2019-error-in-visual-studio-2010)
but compiling with QT didn't work.

Anyway, according to my searches it seems to be a linking problem. My doubt is that I already compiled OpenCV (without QT) but I can use the createTrackbar normally.

I tried using the createButton as this:

```
cv::createButton("buttonCanny",    buttonCallBackCanny,NULL,CV_RADIOBOX,true);
```

But I get this error:

> undefined reference to `cv::createButton(std::string const&, void
>   (*)(int, void*), void*, int, bool)'

I tried the cvCreateButton but I get the same error.

I have this setup
C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> MingGW C++ Linker -> Libraries (all the .dll from compiled OpenCV)

- libopencv_calib3d230
- opencv_ffmpeg
- libopencv_contrib230
- libopencv_core230
- libopencv_features2d230
- libopencv_flann230
- libopencv_gpu230
- libopencv_highgui230
- libopencv_imgproc230
- libopencv_legacy230
- libopencv_ml230
- libopencv_objdetect230
- libopencv_video230

C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> MingGW C++ Linker -> Search Path ("C:\opencvbin\bin" where the Dll are)

C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Includes
"C:\OpenCV2.3\build\include"

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you also added the Qt DLLs to the project?

Comment: @borges ok, I added the wrong library, I forgot about C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin.. do you know what libraries should I add?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I made some mistakes.

Firstly, I wasn't downloading the source code of QT, only the SDK, without source code. 
The necessary libs and executables where there.

Secondly, I had to add some entries in the CMake Gui,

I was ignoring this message:
Could NOT find Qt4 (missing:  QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE QT_RCC_EXECUTABLE QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE QT_INCLUDE_DIR QT_LIBRARY_DIR QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY)

then, I set

- QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE = C:\Qt\4.8.0\bin\qmake.exe
- QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE  = C:\Qt\4.8.0\bin\moc.exe
- QT_RCC_EXECUTABLE = C:\Qt\4.8.0\bin\rcc.exe
- QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE = C:\Qt\4.8.0\bin\uic.exe
- QT_INCLUDE_DIR = C:\Qt\4.8.0\include

and it worked fine.

Trackbar seems to work without Qt, so they probably use their own implementation of a trackbar when there is no Qt available.

Thanks!

Comment: Accept this as the official answer when you can. Click on the checkbox near the answer.