# How to setup linkage for OpenCV and Qt to use createButton?

Tags: c++, opencv, qt4

I'm looking at opencv highgui samples (like connectedcomponents.cpp) and trying to get used to  adding GUI elements. Currently I'm trying to add a button:

```
void on_button(int, void*){
    cout << "click" << end;
}
//in main()
createButton("test",on_button);
```

but I get a link error:

```
g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -Wall -W -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtCore -I../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include -I/opt/local/include -I../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include -I. -F/Users/george/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -headerpad_max_install_names -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -o CVConnectedComponent main.o   -F/Users/george/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib -L/Users/george/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib /opt/local/lib/libopencv_core.dylib /opt/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.dylib /opt/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.dylib /opt/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.dylib /opt/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.dylib /opt/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.dylib /opt/local/lib/libopencv_video.dylib -framework QtCore -F/Users/george/Documents/Qt/CVConnectedComponent/../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib/ 
Undefined symbols:
  "cv::createButton(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, void (*)(int, void*), void*, int, bool)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
make: Leaving directory `/Users/george/Documents/Qt/CVConnectedComponent'
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

As far as I can understand I'm not linking against the QtCore library properly.
I've this:

```
mac: LIBS += -framework QtCore
```

and this:

```
mac: LIBS += -F$$PWD/../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib/ -framework QtCore

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include
```

In the .pro file of the Qt project, but with no luck.
I'm using OpenCV 2.4.1 with Qt 4.7.4 on osx 10.6.8.

What's the correct way to link to QtCore in Qt Creator to use createButton in OpenCV ?

Comment: `cv::createButton` is not a part of `Qt` framework. (Even if it were, you would have to link against both `QtCore` & `QtGui`). You probably should link against `highgui`

Comment: I didn't know that, I thought highgui references Qt behind the scenes. I'm linked to libopencv_highgui.dylib already, but still getting the Symbol not found error

Comment: And I've tried linking against both QtCore and QtGui frameworks with no luck :(

Comment: Did you build OpenCV yourself?  (Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458668/opencv-2-2-createbutton-lnk-2019-error-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: @RA. No, I've used macports and I don't know if by default it's built with Qt support. I was pleased to see it's built with ffmpeg for example, but it might not be built with Qt support. Any easy way to find out ?

Comment: @RA. Ok, I've updated my opencv install with qt4 support. I don't get the link errors anymore, but I don't see a button either. Any hints ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reinstalled OpenCV, this time with Qt support and the code worked.
Still it's worth remembering that buttons will go into the Control Panel by default, as I found out by [reading some documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/highgui_qt_new_functions.html):

[image: OpenCV Qt GUI]